# Trailing change his color when expanded

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have this situation, I created an ExpansionTile using the code below, it is working fine, but when expanded, the trailing changes color, black to white, it was happening with the title and subtitle, but I defined the style manually to solve it, but how can I do this to trailing?

````
ExpansionTile(
   leading: Icon(
     Icons.library_music,
     size: 40.0,
     color: SECONDARYCOLOR,
   ),
   title: Text(
      'Pop Rock',
      style: TextStyle(
         fontSize: 12,
         color: Colors.black,
      ),
   ),
   subtitle: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
         Text(
            'Músicas: 30',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
         ),
         Text(
            'Duração: 2:20',
            style: TextStyle(
               fontSize: 12,
               color: Colors.black,
            ),
         ),
      ],
   ),
   children: <Widget>[
      Column(
         children: <Widget>[
            Text('_buildExpandableContent(policies[i])'),
         ],
      ),
   ],
),```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question look like this one: [Custom style or theme for Expansion Tile Header, Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49557555/custom-style-or-theme-for-expansion-tile-header-flutter)

I've tested a bit of code in DartPad and you can define the color for both your leading and trailing icons using something like that:

```dart
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(unselectedWidgetColor: SECONDARYCOLOR),
  child: ExpansionTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.library_music, size: 40.0),
    title: Text(
      'Pop Rock',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 12,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    ),
    subtitle: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          'Músicas: 30',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          'Duração: 2:20',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    children: <Widget>[
      Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('_buildExpandableContent(policies[i])'),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily set colours for title, subtitle, and icons (leading and trailing), both for when they are collapsed or expanded, with the following properties of the `ExpandedTile`:

- `textColor`: color of title and subtitle when expanded
- `collapsedTextColor`: color of title and subtitle when collapsed
- `iconColor`: color of leading and trailing icons when expanded
- `collapsedIconColor`: color of leading and trailing icons when collapsed

Answer (score 0):

In my case to support both states - collapsed and expanded - for icon color, had to use a combination of the following:

1. In *ExpansionTile* set property: `iconColor`

```
    Widget expansionTile = ExpansionTile(

        iconColor: Colors.white,

        title: Text('Visible'),
        children: [
           Text('Expanded element')
        ]
    );
```

2. Then wrap that in a *Theme*, and set: `unselectedWidgetColor`

```
    expansionTile = Theme(
        data: Theme.of(_ctxt).copyWith(
          unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: expansionTile);
```